# Is it possible the four chaos gods of the Warhammer 40K franchise were once mortal?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In Aaron Dembski-Dowden's great novel *The First Heretic*, there are lines

> And you are not the first Colchisians to reach this world. Khanne, Tezen, Slanat, Narag, all ventured here, millennia ago, guided by visions of angels.

Since they were guided, is it possible the four chaos gods were once mortal?

Comment: Did you mean `is IT possible THAT four chaos gods were mortal`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This passage is not historical fact.  Instead, it is something that is said to Lorgar to get him further down the path to Chaos.

I know of no evidence that suggests Khorne, Slannesh, Tezench or Nurgle were ever mortal.

After some research, I found the following:

The author, ADB, himself states (at http://www.warseer.com/forums/showthread.php?235724-The-First-Heretic/page8):

> It's a parable, about 4 travellers leaving Colchis and finding some
>   vague truth / travelling to that region of space before it was the Eye
>   / a reference to how Colchisians have always been pilgrims / a
>   reference to how Chaos is eternal / a suggestion that a Chaos presence
>   was always in that region of space to some degree and that humanity
>   has forever been drawn to it / a way of suggesting to the Colchisian
>   characters in the novel that their homeworld has always been chosen
>   and inspired by Chaos.
>
> It's not saying anything specific, and for the record, nor is it a
>   retcon. It's a throwaway line about a legend. It's impossible that it
>   could ever make sense. So obviously, it doesn't. Just a Colchisian
>   version of the Odyssey, or the Bible, or the Mahabarat.

Comment: Perfect answer，thanks for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you do a search for warhammer timeline most of them will say something along the lines of: M8 "Birth of Chaos Gods" Slannesh wasnt a mortal Eldar gave birth to Slaneesh by beeing hedonistic in the extreme.
the other 3 dudes could have been mortal at some time.